# PHP split text after space

Tags: php, forms, post, split

I have created a form that has a name and email address input.

```
Name: John Smith
Email: johnsmith@example.com
```

What I want to do is split the name in to first name and surname from the posted.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are escaping user input and there is a validation to add space between name.

If that is already not implemented you could implement them otherwise consider to use separate input box for both first name and last name.

```
$name=explode(" ",$_POST['name']);
echo $name[0]; //first name
echo $name[1];// last name
```

Comment: You'd better add a limit to explode, or you will break on e.g. "Peter van Zantem" or something like that.

Comment: If they entered a name which was John Matt Smith how can i just get the last and first names only?

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = 'John Smith';
list($name, $surname) = explode(' ', $user);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name_array = explode(" ",$name);
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). But note that this will only work if there is only one space in it.

```
$name = "John Smith";
$parts = explode(' ', $name);
$firstName = $parts[0];
$surname = $parts[1];
```